# Linear Algebra over integers modulo 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I've studied linear algebra about a decade ago and now I teach linear algebra to my colleges.

The problem is, my colleges are interested in computer science and/or deep learning and I meet needs about linear algebra on finite field, especially $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I had scrutinized several books, from Linear algebra by Lang, Algebra by Lang, Linear algebra by Friedberg, etc.

However, I cannot find proper book that formulates linear algebra on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or finite fields.

Is there any appropriate references?

Comment: I don't know any references, but almost everything works the same. As long as you don't have to divide by 2. It does need scrutiny, though, because those pesky divisions can hide pretty well. So a book might not be a bad idea. Just saying you can probably get pretty far with only standard resources.

Comment: "Colleagues" not "colleges" is the word you want, I believe.

Comment: I find it surprising that you can't find a book the formulates linear algebra over any arbitrary field, which includes finite fields. What issues are you running into?